# clojure ubergraph compiling error - 'namespace 'ubergraph.core' not found

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, cider, clojure-core.logic

I have been using ubergraph last few weeks up until this morning, but now am having compiling problem.

In my project.clj's dependencies, ubergraph is declared:

```
(defproject graph-alg "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
               [ubergraph "0.8.2"]]
```

In my core.clj, I have

(ns gaph-alg.core
(:require [ubergraph.core :as uber]))

Even with these settings, when compiling in emacs, I kept having this error message:

> *Error compiling c:/.Clojure/snippets/graphworks/graph-alg/src/graph_alg/core.clj at
> (1:1)
> #:clojure.error{:phase :compile-syntax-check,
> :line 1,
> :column 1,
> :source
> "c:/.Clojure/snippets/graphworks/graph-alg/src/graph_alg/core.clj"}
>
> 1. Caused by java.lang.Exception    namespace 'ubergraph.core' not found*

I recreated new projects using lein few times with above setting, but still have same issue like above.

I am not sure whether this comes from emacs cider-repl or something else.

Does anybody else know how to handle this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can narrow the problem by trying it in a REPL free of Emacs and CIDER.  For example, "lein repl".

Comment: The error message means that Ubergraph is not on the Java classpath.  You can inspect the classpath in the REPL by evaluating `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")`.

Comment: I checked the java.class.path and found ubergraph-0.8.2.jar in the path.

Comment: I tried: new lein project, added the dep, started a repl and did `(:require [ubergraph.core :as uber])` - worked. Since you stated you already tried with a fresh template.  Is there a chance you could share your project in full (e.g. on some git site)?

Comment: I found that this error comes from my dumb mistake - I added ubergraph & dorothy in my project.clj file with dorothy version 0.0.7, which conflicts with ubergraph's dorothy version. 
After I downgraded dorothy version to 0.0.6, which is the same version that ubergraph is using, it works fine. 

Thank you so much guys - Phill & cfrick - for your helpful comments!